Increasing the space between two columns of traditionalpoem
Disclaimer: I borrowed the code form here.
I am wondering how to increase the space between two columns of traditionalpoem.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} % 
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % 
\usepackage{bidipoem}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar.ttf}
\begin{document}
\setLTR
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{persian}
دست برداشتن به مناجات به دستیاری ارباب حاجات
\begin{traditionalpoem}
خداوند ز هستی ساده بودیم&
نخست از نیست ما را هست کردی\\
ز ضعف ناتوانایی رهاندی&
فرستادی به ما روشن کتابی\\
میان نیک و بد تخلیط کردیم&
ره فرمودنیها کم سپردیم\\
تو نگذشتی ز دستور عنایت&
بر آن نور از تو گیرم پوششی نیست\\
ز ناکوشیدن خود در خروشیم&
چو دانا همچو نادان گشته غرق است\\
دستانهای نفس ناخوش آهنگ &
\end{traditionalpoem}
\end{persian}

\end{document}


You're more likely to get an answer if you post an example everyone can compile. Most people won't be able to compile this and won't know off-hand how to make it compile or whether what's needed to make it compile will change the output in ways which undermine the question.

Also, how can there be vertical space between two columns? Do you mean horizontal space?

I don't have the correct font to typeset your example and I don't know what it could mean to increase vertical spacing between columns of text. I've therefore substituted another font and assumed you meant to ask how you can increase the horizontal space between the columns of text.
I do not know if switching fonts affects the result in ways which might change the solution you need. I suspect not because I took the solution straight out of the documentation. Since you're not using it and don't mention it, I doubt there's a font-specific catch here.
I know nothing whatsoever about Arabic of any form.
Caveat emptor ...
The following alters the column separation using the formula given in bidi's documentation (page 16). I've put it inside persian but outside traditionalpoem, so it will affect all poems within this block of Persian. If you want to change it globally, move it to the preamble. If you want to change it only for this particular poem, put an extra pair of curly brackets ('braces') around both the line and the poem.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{bidipoem}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Adobe Arabic}
\begin{document}
\setLTR
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{persian}
\renewcommand\poemcolsepskip{30pt}%
دست برداشتن به مناجات به دستیاری ارباب حاجات
\begin{traditionalpoem}
خداوند ز هستی ساده بودیم&
نخست از نیست ما را هست کردی\\
ز ضعف ناتوانایی رهاندی&
فرستادی به ما روشن کتابی\\
میان نیک و بد تخلیط کردیم&
ره فرمودنیها کم سپردیم\\
تو نگذشتی ز دستور عنایت&
بر آن نور از تو گیرم پوششی نیست\\
ز ناکوشیدن خود در خروشیم&
چو دانا همچو نادان گشته غرق است\\
دستانهای نفس ناخوش آهنگ &
\end{traditionalpoem}
\end{persian}

\end{document}

I get warnings on compilation, but they seem to be related to the font. I assume you don't get them for the font you're using - this just happened to be the first one I found with Arabic in the name which promised to support Persian script. (I seem to have forgotten how to get fontconfig to tell me which font it uses for what.)
Given an insanely annoying bug in Okular, I can't post an image of anything worth squat right now, so at least you will be saved the sight of whatever monstrosity Adobe's mangling does to the poem.
Note that I have no idea if the result is good, bad or indifferent so far as typesetting Arabic is concerned. All I can tell you is that it definitely increases the horizontal space between the columns.
